# Is it possible to add a delay between server-sent events?

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, chatgpt-api

I'm using the `stream=true` flag on OpenAI's `/v1/chat/completions` endpoint (https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create).

Currently, I process server sent events by assigning each incoming chunk a timestamp using `Date.now()` and adding that to a document in Firestore. The client will then sort these chunks based on the timestamp and append them together.

For example, this is what one example document looks like:
[image: A screenshot of the Firestore Document]

The problem with this approach is... the chunks are sometimes sent too quickly!

For example, `chunk1` could have a timestamp of `1682970460319` and if `chunk2` is sent quickly enough, it can have the same `Date.now()` timestamp of `1682970460319`, resulting in a collision.

The only work around I can think of is whether it's possible to add a small delay in between server sent events in order to prevent collisions. Otherwise, I'm not too sure on how I can fix this issue.

Here's my https call:

```
const req = https.request(
    {
      hostname: "api.openai.com",
      port: 443,
      path: "/v1/chat/completions",
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + apiKey,
      },
    },
    function (res) {
      res.on("data", async (data) => {
        const timestamp = Date.now();
        // Messages in the event stream are separated by a pair of newline characters.
        const payloads = data.toString().split("\n\n");
        for (const payload of payloads) {
          if (payload.includes("[DONE]")) return;
          if (payload === undefined) continue;
          if (payload.startsWith("data:")) {
            const data = payload.replaceAll(/(\n)?^data:\s*/g, ""); // in case there's multiline data event
            try {
              const delta = JSON.parse(data.trim());
              const content = delta.choices[0].delta?.content;
              console.log({content, timestamp})
              if (!content) continue;
              await handleNewChunk(content, timestamp);
            } catch (error) {
              console.log(`Error with JSON.parse and ${payload}.\n${error}`);
            }
          }
        }
      });
      res.on("end", () => {
        console.log("No more data in response.");
      });
    }
  );
```

Comment: You shouldn't use a timestamp at all here.  If the chunks have a natural ordering and you're processing them in that order, then just use the index of the order and keep incrementing for each one.

Comment: You're right! I recently came to the same conclusion ‍♂️.

Answer (score 0):

As Doug said in his comment using a timestamp here isn’t right. Because chunks have natural ordering, I ended up using an index that I increment after every chunk.